# How to write a text list to a defined csv file? Python selenium scraping

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to Python, so please forgive me if this is a simple issue.

I am web scraping an entire experience section from Linkedin using Selenium. Below is my relevant code:

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver

ChromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/jones/Downloads/chromedriver')

driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/in/pauljgarner/')

##writing 'Name' to excel
writer = csv.writer(open(parameters.file_name, 'w', encoding='utf8'))
writer.writerow(['Name'])

name = sel.xpath('normalize-space(//li[@class="inline t-24 t-black t-normal break-words"])').extract_first()

writer.writerow([name])

##scraping the entire work experience section:

experience = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//section[@id = "experience-section"]/ul//li')
for item in experience:
    print(item.text)
    print("")
```

The output I get from the experience section is a text list that looks like the below:

```
Freelance Python Developer
Company Name
Depop
Dates Employed
Jun 2015 – Present
Employment Duration
4 yrs 11 mos
Location
London, United Kingdom
Python development using: Django, PostgreSQL, ElasticSearch, TensorFlow, Redis, gevent, Mongodb, Django REST Framework
```

I want to write this output into the same excel sheet I used to capture the 'Name'.

The excel format I'm looking for would look like:

```
Name  Title   CompanyName  DatesEmployed  EmploymentDuration  Location  Description
Paul  Freel.. Depop        Jun 2015 – P.. 4 yrs 11 mos        London    Python Dev..
```

The issue is that I do not know how to convert the text list I scraped from the experience section into the same Excel sheet that I defined earlier with a specific element (with 'Names').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
from selenium import webdriver

ChromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/shubham/Downloads/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/in/pauljgarner/')


rows = []

name = sel.xpath('normalize-space(//li[@class="inline t-24 t-black t-normal break-words"])').extract_first()
experience = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//section[@id = "experience-section"]/ul//li')

rows.append([name])
for item in experience:
    rows[0].append(item)
    print(item.text)
    print("")

with open(parameters.file_name, 'w', encoding='utf8') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerows(rows)
```

Comment: Hi Shubham, Thanks for your answer. The code ran without error, but the excel file still doesn't seem quite right. Instead of the observations in the experience section printing, each cell has a string that looks like: ```<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="4a06b20b8e051c532fbe7a333a4d6aec", element="beb29e54-aab5-4da6-9026-1fb5dd1fe3c0")>```   The cell for xpath 'Name', however, printed correctly

Comment: Update: I edited the code to be ```rows[0].append(item.text)``` but this Excel output only prints one row. Each item in experience prints as one cell, instead of multiple column variables (Company, Years of Experience, etc.) with observations (such as in the ideal output I'd described above)

Comment: I suspect the issue is that a delimiter will need to be inserted in the text list for the .csv to put them in separate columns, but am not sure how to do that in this case