# How to specify that the delimiter is a line break when writing to csv? Python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, csv

I have extracted a list of text from a section of a website. Specifically, I scraped the 'experience' section of Linkedin and have extracted each work experience item within that section.

However, the data is in the form of a text list, and I am having issues formatting it as a csv file in the way that I want.

My relevant code is below:

```
from selenium import webdriver

ChromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/jones/Downloads/chromedriver')

driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/in/pauljgarner/')

rows = []

name = sel.xpath('normalize-space(//li[@class="inline t-24 t-black t-normal break-words"])').extract_first()
experience = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//section[@id = "experience-section"]/ul//li')

rows.append([name])
for item in experience:
    rows[0].append(item.text)
    print(item.text)
    print("")

with open(parameters.file_name, 'w', encoding='utf8') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerows(rows)
```

The excel output I am getting from this code is below:

[image]

As you can see, it seems like a line break is separating each observation.

My desired excel output is below:

(Note that each text list has it's own variable names. For example, Company Name is for the first text list, and Company Name_2 for the second text list).

[image]

I suspect that I need to find a way to specify in Python that a line break is a delimiter in each list of text. However, I am unsure of how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Disclosure: I posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60983670/how-to-write-a-text-list-to-a-defined-csv-file-python-selenium-scraping) on this same issue a few days ago, but I am posting a more specific question on delimiters because I haven't seen anything about specifying linebreaks as a delimiter in writing to csv with Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to split each element of rows on '\n'.
You also need to specify the headers to get the desired output.

```
headers = ['Name', 'Title', ... ]

with open(parameters.file_name, 'w', encoding='utf8') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(headers)
    for row in rows:
        writer.writerow(row.split('\n'))
```

Comment: Hi Eric, this approach makes sense to me. But when I run this, I get the error ```AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'```

Comment: If each row is a list, then select the element that has the content and split it.